# Measure of Interestingness?

Tags: data-mining

Can anyone explain what a measure of interestingness of an itemset means in data mining?

The google results are not all the helpful for understanding. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of itemset mining is to find interesting patterns  that occurs often in a set of transactions. A pattern in itemset mining is a group of items.

There can be a lot of patterns.  To automatically evaluate which patterns are interesting and which one are not, interestingness measures are used by itemset mining algorithms.

In itemset mining, the original measure is the "support". It is simply how many times a group of items occurs in a transaction database.

There exists many other measures that can be used.  In association rules mining for example, the lift, confidence, all_confidence, cosine, etc. are measures that can be used.

For more details about interestingness measures, I recommend the book by Tan & Kumar & Steinbach, which has a free chapter on their website discussing the advantages of several interestingness measures for association rule mining (which is related to itemset mining because itemsets are used to generate rules).

Answer (score 0):

Google's Page Rank thinks the web page that has the most references from other web pages is the most interesting.  It's a gross simplification of the way Page Rank works, but it's an example of one measure of what interesting might mean.

It's a metric that you come up with from your imagination.  There are many; some work better than others under different circumstances.

Comment: In fact, one could contribute lots of Google's success lies in its formula for interestingness "working better than others" :-)

Comment: How ironic that the Google searches weren't helpful.  I think the problem is the OP not knowing what they're looking for.

Comment: I see. So what if I the following 3 sets of things
ABC, AB, AC. Would the element the occurs the most here, A, be a good measure of interestingness?

Comment: Apparently not.  My personal level of interest is zero.  You'll need another measure.